# How to move a button to "center-bottom" in ionic2

Tags: css

How to set something to be in center horizontally and bottom vertically?

I tried to use flex as `class="layout horizontal"` like in Polymer...

```
<ion-content class="layout vertical">
  <span class="flex"></span>
<button danger round class="center">Hibás</button>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a question of style (CSS) rather than framework (Ionic) I use the following which works well.

```
<ion-content padding class="">

  <p>Some content</p>

  <div class="bottom" text-center>
    <button block>Submit</button> 
  </div>

</ion-content>
```

And in my style sheet (app/theme/app.core.scss):

```
.bottom {
  padding: $content-padding;
  position: fixed;
  bottom:0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really an Ionic2 question, more CSS styling issue.

Try something similar to [trying to align html button at the center of the my page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11799159/trying-to-align-html-button-at-the-center-of-the-my-page?answertab=votes#tab-top)